# Memory usage for a recursive program in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, v8

I want to run a function again after sometime once the execution is completed. I have written 3 programs but I am not sure about the memory usage of the programs and which one would be the most efficient way of doing this.

Approach 1 -

```
async function main() {
  const random = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000);
  const arr = new Array(random).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);

  const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  console.log(result);

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  main();
}

main();
```

Approach 2 -

```
async function main() {
  const random = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000);
  const arr = new Array(random).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);

  const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  console.log(result);

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  await main();
}

main();
```

Approach 3 -

```
async function main() {
  const random = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000);
  const arr = new Array(random).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);

  const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  console.log(result);

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}

const run = () => {
  main().then(() => {
    run();
  });
};

run();
```

I am not sure which one would be the best way to do this. I think that the memory usage would increase in case of other languages and hence, this question is specifically related to node js event loop, would it keep the variables of previous iteration?

Comment: approach 4, don't use promises async/await ... just do `setTimeout(main, 3000)` at the end of `main` - the only "approach" I'd be wary of is approach 2, why would you `await main()` since you don't need the result of calling `main()`

Comment: I don't need the result in approach 2, but I just want to know if using await will make a difference, or it would be same as the first approach. Also I need to use async await because this is just a normal program but I would need to do an api call in the function or a database call which would need to be awaited.

Comment: Didn't get that, this is just a sample program to simulate the memory that will be used in a program. I just want to know if making a recursive call based on the above 3 approaches would result in memory leaks?

Comment: Approach 2 likely does leak memory, since it builds up an ever-growing pool of never-resolved promises. Consider using a simple `while (true)` loop instead

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried testing this yourself?

Since this is clearly a reduced toy example, you might as well eliminate randomness, to make individual test runs more easily comparable. Just always allocate large arrays.
You can also reduce the interval (e.g. to 0) so you don't have to wait as long before you see long-term effects.
With those changes, you can observe within ~10 seconds which of your approaches leak memory (because they'll crash due to running out of memory), and which don't.
(I'm intentionally not posting the results of my own test runs, because I'm trying to help you help yourself.)

Aside from memory leaks, infinite recursion is also something to avoid, because it'll eventually throw a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. This, too, is easy to test yourself; in this case you'll want to make the function body as cheap as possible (no allocations at all) to make the test run as quickly as possible.
(Hint: *at least* one of your approaches runs into this problem.)

> which one would be the most efficient way of doing this.

The first thing that stands out is `parseInt(Math.random()...)`. While its relative impact is negligible in this case, this is a rather inefficient pattern: it converts the number to a string and then parses it back to a number. Use `Math.round()` instead (or `Math.trunc()`, depending on desired behavior) to make this a lot more efficient.

Of course the whole "allocate an array, fill it, then reduce it" approach is also a super inefficient way to compute the sum of the numbers 1..N. As an efficient alternative, use Gauss' direct formula instead. But that's probably just meant to be a useless example, not what you actually care about.

For the repeated execution itself: use a loop instead of recursion. Or, even simpler, use `setTimeout(main, 3000)` (at the end of `main`) directly; there's no need to await a dummy Promise just to achieve a delay before a function call.

Comment: hi, I tried running it on my own to test it and found that 1st and the 3rd program had around similar kind of memory usage. However, the 2nd one kept on restarting again and again may because of memory leaks I think (I was using pm2 to start the processes and see there memory usage). I am still not sure about the reason though.

Comment: @hemantjangid As Bergi said in his comment, (2) builds an ever-growing pool of promises that never get resolved because `main` never returns. (1) has infinite recursion and will throw a `RangeError` when it runs out of stack space (remove the delay to see that happen very quickly!). (3) should be okay but is unnecessarily complicated.